# Mosaico with WordPress Unexpected errors

Tags: wordpress, mosaico

I am working with the Mosaico extension in WordPress with Civi 4.7.20.

If I go to build a template the template builder loads OK. I get several errors when working on the template.

1. When a template loads the image placement areas do not show an image and if I upload an image I get an internal server error.
2. When I try to save an template I get an unexpected error, please contact us. This only occurs on the versafix-1 template the tedc15 template saves OK.

Not sure if it is a bug or configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug - and it looks like it has been reported upstream:

https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues/160

The temporary fix is to add an Alias to your Apache or Nginx configuration. I added the following for nginx:

```
location /templates/versafix-1/ {
  alias /srv/longshore/platforms/ourpowerbase-d7-c4.7.19/sites/all/extensions/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/packages/mosaico/templates/versafix-1/;
}
```